# Prevent spring-cloud-aws-messaging from trying to stop the queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-aws

I'm using `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` in a Spring Boot project.
I have SQS queue created manually in AWS.

It is being used like:

```
@SqsListener("${sqs.name.incoming}")
public void listen(String message) {
    ...
}
```

It works fine. But when I stop my application in IDE, or when the Spring Boot tests finish, it tries to stop the queue. It can't stop it and eventually times out. It throws this exception:

```
2019-10-29 15:40:07.949  WARN 10378 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.m.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : An exception occurred while stopping queue 'my-awesome-queue-name'

java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.waitForRunningQueuesToStop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:161) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.stop(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:351) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.stop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.stop(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:239) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.stop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-aws-messaging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:238) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:377) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1018) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:945) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar:5.1.10.RELEASE]
```

This waiting slows down application or tests shutdown.

How do I tell `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` that it is a manually created queue and it should not try to shut it down?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not actually shutting down the the SQS queue rather it is shutting down the running task that is polling the queue. The default timeout to shut this down is 10 secs as defined in `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.queueStopTimeout`.

When the task is polling the queue, it waits for messages from 1 to 20 secs as set in `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.waitTimeOut`. If this poll happens to be greater than 10 secs, then the above shutdown will timeout causing the `TimeoutException`.

So to fix this, either you increase the `queueStopTimeout` to be greater than 20

```
@PostConstruct
public void setUpListenerContainer() {
    listenerContainer.setQueueStopTimeout(25000);
}
```

or decrease the poll `waitTimeOut` to be less than 10.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setWaitTimeOut(5);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was answered by someone at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/504. Accepting your answer anyway, cheers.

Comment: Cool. I raised an issue if they can set the default to >20 to avoid this exception. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/507

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @AdrianM How do you get the `listenerContainer` ?